# Radial Basis Function Network (RBF Network)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, biological-neural-network

According to the link below, i didn't understand what is the "center vector for neuron i", in other words "center of the RBF units called also prototype ".

[read the Network architecture in this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_network)

Please i need your appreciated help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read on to the **Training** section in your link, it explains what the centre vectors are:

[image: rbf]

Reading the above, it seems to me that you have your set of samples, the *x*'s, and from these you choose a number of centre vectors - one for each neuron in the hidden layer . The centre vectors, broadly speaking are centres of clusters in your sample data.

As the remarks say, you can use an unsupervised clustering algorithm, such as k-means, to find *n* cluster centres in your data, where *n* is the number of neurons in the hidden layer that you are dealing with. Different layers may have more or less neurons and so will have correspondingly more or less centre vectors.

Then the RBF relates each individual sample, *x*, to each centre vector by some function of the Euclidean distance between them.

Comment: I know that x corresponds to the input. But if we consider that we have 3 units in the hidden layer and one input x. This last is therefore connected to all RBF units. So each unit in the hidden layer must implement a radial basis function which corresponds to the euclidean distance between the input x and its own center ? If we consider that this center is calculated in a specific manner, so how the input x is calculated ? Please i need a help :) thank's in advance.

Comment: @Liszt see updated answer above - is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes it's very clear now. I thank you very much for your explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

The center vector of the neuron are the centers of the RBF. RBF is just a function the distance of a point (called x in the article) to a center (called ci in the article). Each neuron has its own center.